# controller name in the url in codeigniter to be more than one

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have 3 controllers are home, food, and drink. home controller I want to make the default controller. and I wrote in routes.php file like this:

```
 $ route ['default_controller'] = "home";

 $ route ['404_override '] ='';
```

then i made the code in each controller as below:

controller home.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){

    }

    public function info(){

    }
}
```

controller food.php

```
class Food extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){

    }

    public function foodMenu(){

    }
    public function foodJenis(){

    }

}
```

controller drink.php

```
class Drink extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){

    }

    public function drinkMenu(){

    }
    public function drinkJenis(){

    }

}
```

I want to make this url like www.mydomain.com/home, www.mydomain.com/food, www.mydomain.com/food/foodmenu, www.mydomain.com/food/foodjenis, www.mydomain.com/drink, www.mydomain.com/drink/drinkmenu, www.mydomain.com/drink/drinkjenis.

but when I was on the url www.mydomain.com/food/foodmenu and I headed to www.mydomain.com/food/foodjenis, but the url that appears is www.mydomain.com/food/food/foodjenis. **"food"** controller name in the url it into two. how to handle it. please help me. thank you :(

Comment: Use absolute links, not relative ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you set base url in config file in CI ?If yes. try with relative paths. like food/foodjenis

```
<a href="<? php echo base_url('food/foodjenis') ?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve is through the use of `base` tag.

Somewhere in the document head (before including any css or js) put

```
<base href='http://mysite.com'>
```

After that you can freely use relative links in your CI applications.

Answer (score 1):

How do u make your links?

I think there is problem u try to make relative linking and html is looking at food as a folder so when u make link as

```
<a href="food/foodjenis"></a>
```

it will make link as u wrote www.mydomain.com/food/food/foodjenis

But if u use CI url

```
  <a href="<? php echo site_url('food/foodjenis') ?>"></a>
```

It shall work like u intended.